# How do you specify multiple paths in Git command?

Tags: git

On [this site](http://nicolasgallagher.com/git-checkout-specific-files-from-another-branch/) it explains how to use the command...

```
git checkout <branch_name> -- <paths>
```

But the `paths` is plural.

Does this mean we can specify several paths in one command?

If so, what is the syntax for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does this mean we can specify several paths in one command?

Yep, just separate them by spaces:

```
git checkout -- path/to/file some/other/file even/more/files
```